# Selecting values using \d

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with values:

```
--Product--
ASUS22
ASUSI522
ASUSI7256
ASUSI2262
ASUSI1267
ASUSI764
ASUSI712
```

and so on. I'm trying to select products with it starting with ASUSI and only 3 integers after it.

Somebody said I  can use \d\d\d in order to achieve that but it doesn't work(below)

```
select product from products where product like '%ASUS\d\d\d%'
```

So I want to select values :

```
ASUSI712
ASUSI764
ASUSI522
```

How can do this?
Thanks,
Regards,

Comment: When you say `doesnt work` what mean? error or incorrect result?

Comment: It just returns empty

Comment: `ASUSI522aaa` should be returned or not?

Comment: `LIKE` [isn't described](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html) as recognizing `\d` or character ranges. Perhaps, you want `SIMILAR TO` with `[0-9]{3}` instead of `\d\d\d`. Also, many of the values you listed wanting have a letter, `I`, following `ASUS`. Those shouldn't be matched by a pattern expecting a digit (`ASUS\d`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use character classes, you need to use `SIMILAR TO` instead of `LIKE`:

```
select product from products where product similar to '%ASUS\d\d\d'
```

As @lad2025 notes, your original query does not match your expectation, so you need remove the final `%` to restrict the match to three numbers.

Comment: `ASUS7256` will be returned

Comment: @lad2025: True, I thought the regexp was given. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression you want to match the string `ASUSI` with exactly three digits after it is:

```
^ASUSI\d{3}$

^ASUSI  - starts with 'ASUSI'
\d{3}   - followed by exactly three digits
$       - followed by the end of the string

SELECT product
FROM products
WHERE product ~ '^ASUSI\d{3}d$'
```

Comment: Are you working with Java or something? I just tried it in `psql` and it works fine without any escaping.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more direct way, but you could use `length()` to achieve this:

```
SELECT product
FROM   products
WHERE  product like 'ASUSI%'
AND    length(product) = 8
AND    product ~ '\d$'
```

Comment: "product" ~ '\d$' to make sure last 3 char are a number

Answer (score -1):

How about this ? using LIKE ASUSI and using 3 characters checking for range 1  to 9.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE(Product VARCHAR(15))
INSERT INTO @test(Product)
VALUES('ASUS22'),
('ASUSI522'),
('ASUSI7256'),
('ASUSI2262'),
('ASUSI1267'),
('ASUSI764'),
('ASUSI712'),
('ASUSI72K'),
('ASUSI7234')

SELECT *
FROM @test

SELECT *
FROM @test
WHERE Product LIKE 'ASUSI[1-9][1-9][1-9]'
```

Comment: `\d` includes 0s. This doesn't. This would fail to match a tonne of potential results.

Comment: then you can use [0-9] to include 0s. Can you give me one example this would fail to match any result ?

Comment: `LIKE` does not support "regular expressions" in SQL

Comment: Thanks for your down vote. I agree but OP is asking for "select products with it starting with ASUSI and only 3 integers after it." Then, what's wrong with my T-SQL, it returns the expected output. I'm asking for an example that will fail to return some expected input. I may be wrong but wanted to see.

Comment: @Murthy Of course I can: it would fail to match absolutely any code whose trailing number contained a 0 in any of its three places. And given that the OP was looking for something equivalent to `\d`, and probably isn't pioneering a strange new numeric system where "integer" means 'digit between 1 and 9 but not including 0'... that's almost certainly not what they want.